# Only read specific attribute columns of a shapefile with Geopandas / Fiona

Tags: python, fiona, geopandas

Having [geopandas](http://geopandas.org/) installed in my Python environment, I can read a shapefile into a `geodataframe` with

```
In:
import geopandas as gpd
myShapefile = gpd.read_file(path_to_my_shapefile)
print(myShapefile)

Out:
myShapefile as a geodataframe
```

Unfortunately, I have some shapefiles which contain lots of attribute columns which I don't need in the end, slowing down the reading process a lot. Is there any possibility to limit the reading of the shapefile to specific attribute columns?

In regular pandas, I could use the `usecols` argument to the `read_csv` and `read_table` functions to limit the reading to the specified columns, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv(path_to_my_csv_file, usecols=['onlyThisColumn', 'andThatColumnAsWell', 'butNoOther'])
```

However, using `usecols` in geopandas' `read_file` method gives an error, probably because geopandas uses `Fiona` to read shapefiles which does not accept the argument.

```
  File "C:\Python34-64bit\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py", line 13, in read_file
    with fiona.open(filename, **kwargs) as f:
TypeError: open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'usecols'
```

Is there any other argument or way to achieve this with geopandas/Fiona?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I marked the answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update for this topic:

geopandas & fiona now support reading specifiec columns from files using the `ignore_fields` or `include_fields` parameters in `gpd.read_file()`.

https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/io.html

Answer (score 4):

Building on gene's answer, you can use `GeoDataFrame.from_features`

The following should do the trick:

```
import fiona

def records(filename, usecols, **kwargs):
    with fiona.open(filename, **kwargs) as source:
        for feature in source:
            f = {k: feature[k] for k in ['id', 'geometry']}
            f['properties'] = {k: feature['properties'][k] for k in usecols}
            yield f
```

And then

```
gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(records(filename), ['prop1', 'prop2'])
```

I'd be curious to know if this speeds up your code, or if the properties need to be ignored in Fiona rather than the `GeoDataFrame` construction.

Comment: Uhm, thanks for your support but I got the impression that this did not speed up anything, reading the files takes more or less as long as before :o I just cannot investigate this "scientifically" (using time measurement) at the moment, maybe later today or tomorrow. Did you have a different impression?

Comment: Fiona doesn't support field picking, so there is no speedup: geopandas must read every field and filter them. Could be a good feature, maybe sketch it out at https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues?

Answer (score 2):

You can "simulate" `usecols` with a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

1) Classical method

```
import fiona
layer = fiona.open('test.shp')
layer.schema
{'geometry': 'Point', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'dip', 'int:2'), (u'dipdir', 'int:3'), (u'Type', 'str:10')])}
for feature in layer:
   print feature
{'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (272070.600041, 155389.38792000001)}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '0', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'dip', 30), (u'dipdir, 130), (u'Type', u'incl')])}
{'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (271066.03214800003, 154475.63137700001)}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '1', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'dip', 55), (u'dipdir', 145), (u'Type', u'incl')])}
{'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (273481.498868, 153923.49298800001)}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '2', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'dip', 40), (u'dipdir', 155), (u'Type', u'incl')])}
```

2) With a generator (with only geometry and one column here, but it is easy to adapt)

```
def records(filename, col):
   # the generator
   reader = fiona.open(filename)
   for feat in reader:
          new  = {}
          new['geometry'] = feat['geometry']
          new['properties'] = {}
          new['properties'][col] = feat['properties'][col]
          yield new

 for feat in records("test.shp","dip"):
      print feat
  {'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (272070.600041, 155389.38792000001)}, 'properties': {'dip': 30}}
  {'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (271066.03214800003, 154475.63137700001)}, 'properties': {'dip': 55}}
  {'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (273481.498868, 153923.49298800001)}, 'properties': {'dip': 40}}
```

Comment: As already stated in my comment to jakew's answer, thanks for your approach, but I did not recognize an improvement in reading speed from this. Do you have a different impression?

Comment: No, it is only an alternative approach to give a solution to the question of jakew.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not a direct solution to the problem, but in some cases the following might be helpful.

It is possible to use the [ogr2ogr tool](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to do the attribute filtering in advance and then read the filtered shapefiles with geopandas / Fiona. My subjective impression is that this is faster than reading the unfiltered shapefiles directly (however, I thought both ogr2ogr and Fiona use the same shapefile reading engine under the hood?!).

To do so (with a properly installed GDAL/OGR on your system):

```
def filterShapefilesWithOgr2Ogr(inputFolder, outputFolder, attributesToSave):

    # inputFolder: the folder where the original shapefiles are located
    # outputFolder: the folder where the filtered shapefiles are to be stored
    # attributesToSave: string of attributes that shall be copied into the output, e.g. 'ID, location', length'

    import subprocess

    # traverse through the input folder
    os.chdir(inputFolder)
    for filename in glob.glob('*.shp'):

        # filter each shapefile from the input folder and save it at output folder
        print('filtering ' + filename)
        subprocess.call(["ogr2ogr", "-f", "ESRI Shapefile", "-select", attributesToSave, outputFolder + '/' + filename, filename])

    return
```

If one is only interested into the attributes and not necessarily into the geometry features of the shapefiles, reading only the `dbf` table of the shapefile into a `pandas` `dataFrame` can also speed things up a lot (in my case, 10s vs. 10min).

To do so, I use [dbfread](http://dbfread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (simply install with `pip install dbfread`).

```
def readDBFToDataFrame(inputFolder):

    import glob
    import dbfread import DBF

    # traverse through the input folder
    os.chdir(inputFolder)
    for filename in glob.glob('*.dbf'):

        print('reading dbf file ' + filename)

        # load the dbf file
        table = DBF(filename, load=False)

        # iterate through dbf file and store each record in a list
        listOfRecords = []
        for record in table:
            listOfRecords.append(record)

        # create a pandas dataframe from the list of records
        df = pd.DataFrame(listOfRecords)

    return df
```