# Read N number of rows from shapefile using GeoPandas

Tags: shapefile, geopandas, data-frame

Pandas has a parameter [`nrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for selecting how many rows will be read into the DataFrame.

Does GeoPandas have a similar parameter? Couldn't find in the documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Geopandas 0.7](https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#row-filter) added a new `rows` parameter to `read_file`. You can use it to read the first n rows, or a specific slice of rows.

```
import geopandas as gpd

# Read the first 100 rows
gdf = gpd.read_file("/path/to/my/shapefile.shp", rows=100)

# Read 5 rows from the 100000th
gdf = gpd.read_file("/path/to/my/shapefile.shp", rows=slice(100000, 100005))
```

Comment: great answer! do you know if R has an equivalent?

Answer (score 8):

See [Only read specific rows of a shapefile with GeoPandas / Fiona](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220023/only-read-specific-rows-of-a-shapefile-with-geopandas-fiona):

```
import geopandas as gpd
import fiona

c = fiona.open(r'C:\someshapefile.shp')
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(c[0:5])
```