# Strategies for working with large shapefiles

Tags: r, shapefile

I am interested in learning about how to work with "Road Network" files - for example, I would like to find out the driving distance between two sets of geographical coordinates (i.e. longitude and latitude).

I found this shapefile for the Canadian Road Networks : https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/RNF-FRR/files-fichiers/lrnf000r22a_e.zip - now, I am trying to import this file into R.

Below, this is the code I am using to first download the shapefile to a temporary folder and then try to read the shapefile:

```
library(sf)
library(rgdal)
# Set the URL for the shapefile
url <- "https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/RNF-FRR/files-fichiers/lrnf000r22a_e.zip"

# Create a temporary folder to download and extract the shapefile
temp_dir <- tempdir()
temp_file <- file.path(temp_dir, "lrnf000r22a_e.zip")

# Download the shapefile to the temporary folder
download.file(url, temp_file)

# Extract the shapefile from the downloaded zip file
unzip(temp_file, exdir = temp_dir)

# Read the shapefile using the rgdal package
library(rgdal)
shapefile <- readOGR(dsn = temp_dir, layer = "lrnf000r22a_e")
```

But when trying to run the last line of code (readOGR), I get the following error:

```
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwDKofs", layer: "lrnf000r22a_e"
with 2246324 features
It has 21 fields
Integer64 fields read as strings:  OBJECTID 
Error: memory exhausted (limit reached?)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: OGR support is provided by the sf and terra packages among others 
2: OGR support is provided by the sf and terra packages among others 
3: OGR support is provided by the sf and terra packages among others 
4: OGR support is provided by the sf and terra packages among others 
5: OGR support is provided by the sf and terra packages among others 
6: OGR support is provided by the sf and terra packages among others
```

This seems to be a very large shapefile and my computer does not have enough memory to work with this file.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem before? Are there any strategies I can use to resolving this error?

Note: Perhaps its possible to read this in "chunks"? (e.g. [Read N number of rows from shapefile using GeoPandas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324374/read-n-number-of-rows-from-shapefile-using-geopandas))

Comment: You loaded the `sf` package. It has at least one function for reading shapefiles, `st_read`. I’m not sure if it will be more efficient, but why not try that?

Comment: Another method to consider is using PostGIS via the R API. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpostgis/index.html

Comment: No shapefile can legally exceed 2Gb in the `.shp` or 2Gb in the `.dbf`, so  most modern computers can actually handle all that could be loaded, though it's doubtful that they ever would. Keep in mind that shapefiles were created when 32Mb was a lot of RAM, and filesystems could not handle files in excess of 2Gb. "Very large" in modern parlance is 20-100 million features, which would blow out the maximum file size of a shapefile with complex geometry early on. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348557/how-does-shapefile-2gb-limit-equate-to-70-million-points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `sf` package you can apply an SQL SELECT query to a shapefile read using `st_read` with the `query` argument. For example if you have a huge road network to load you could maybe restrict it to main roads, or roads within a smaller bounding box that you are interested in.

For example to select only the highways:

```
hwy = st_read("./lrnf000r22a_e.shp",
       query="select * from lrnf000r22a_e where TYPE='HWY'")
```

That gets you 115619 features down from the 2.2 million in the full data set.

You can do a lot more filtering with `st_read` including using `query=` to select "chunks" by specifying ID numbers (I think this data set uses `OBJECTID`), and you can also pass a `wkt_filter` parameter to get only data within some polygonal bounds - see the examples in the help for `st_read` for full details.

Comment: @ Spacedman: Thank you so much for your answer! I guess I could also filter on : PRNAME_L (province)?

Comment: I think this is how you would use the code you wrote alongside mine: hwy = st_read(file.path(temp_dir, "lrnf000r22a_e.shp"),
       query="select * from lrnf000r22a_e where TYPE='HWY'")

Comment: Well yes, I had the shapefile downloaded to the working folder. Doesn't change anything with the `select` query though, does it?

Comment: @ Spaceman: Thank you so much for your answer! I posted a follow up question over here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/456838/calculating-driving-distances-from-shapefiles ... can you please take a look at it if you have time?