# Working with tbl_graphs using R

Tags: r, network

I am working with the R programming language.

**Based on a shapefile, I am trying to find out the driving distance between two coordinates (e.g. CN Tower and Toronto Pearson Airport).**

First I loaded the shapefile:

```
library(sf)
library(rgdal)
library(sfnetworks)
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)
library(tidygraph)

# Set the URL for the shapefile
url <- "https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/RNF-FRR/files-fichiers/lrnf000r22a_e.zip"

# Create a temporary folder to download and extract the shapefile
temp_dir <- tempdir()
temp_file <- file.path(temp_dir, "lrnf000r22a_e.zip")

# Download the shapefile to the temporary folder
download.file(url, temp_file)

# Extract the shapefile from the downloaded zip file
unzip(temp_file, exdir = temp_dir)

# Read the shapefile using the rgdal package
# source: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/456748/strategies-for-working-with-large-shapefiles/456798#456798
a = st_read(file.path(temp_dir, "lrnf000r22a_e.shp"), query="select * from lrnf000r22a_e where PRUID_R ='35'")
```

The shapefile looks something like this:

```
Simple feature collection with 570706 features and 21 fields
Geometry type: LINESTRING
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 5963148 ymin: 665490.8 xmax: 7581671 ymax: 2212179
Projected CRS: NAD83 / Statistics Canada Lambert
First 10 features:
   OBJECTID NGD_UID       NAME TYPE  DIR AFL_VAL ATL_VAL AFR_VAL ATR_VAL CSDUID_L                           CSDNAME_L CSDTYPE_L CSDUID_R                           CSDNAME_R CSDTYPE_R PRUID_L PRNAME_L PRUID_R PRNAME_R RANK
1         4 3434819       <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  3526003                           Fort Erie         T  3526003                           Fort Erie         T      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
2         5 1358252      South LINE <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  3551027                Gordon/Barrie Island        MU  3551027                Gordon/Barrie Island        MU      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
3         8 1778927       <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  3512054                           Wollaston        TP  3512054                           Wollaston        TP      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
4        11  731932     Albion   RD <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    2010    2010  3520005                             Toronto         C  3520005                             Toronto         C      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    3
5        18 3123617  County 41   RD <NA>     640     708     635     709  3511015                     Greater Napanee         T  3511015                     Greater Napanee         T      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    3
6        20 4814160       <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  3553005     Greater Sudbury / Grand Sudbury        CV  3553005     Greater Sudbury / Grand Sudbury        CV      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
7        21 1817031       <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  3537028                         Amherstburg         T  3537028                         Amherstburg         T      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
8        24 4825761       <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  3554094 Timiskaming, Unorganized, West Part        NO  3554094 Timiskaming, Unorganized, West Part        NO      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
9        25  544891     Dunelm   DR <NA>       1       9       2      10  3526053                      St. Catharines        CY  3526053                      St. Catharines        CY      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
10       28 1835384 Seven Oaks   DR <NA>     730     974     731     975  3515005             Otonabee-South Monaghan        TP  3515005             Otonabee-South Monaghan        TP      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
   CLASS                 _ogr_geometry_
1     23 LINESTRING (7269806 859183,...
2     23 LINESTRING (6921247 1133452...
3     23 LINESTRING (7320857 1089403..
```

Then I tried to calculate the distance by treating the road network as a graph:

```
# Convert the shapefile to an sfnetwork object
net <- as_sfnetwork(a)

# Define the two points of interest in WGS84 (EPSG:4326)
pt1 <- st_point(c(-79.61203, 43.68312))
pt2 <- st_point(c(-79.61203, 43.64256))

# Set the CRS of the points to WGS84 (EPSG:4326)
pt1 <- st_sfc(pt1, crs = 4326)
pt2 <- st_sfc(pt2, crs = 4326)

# Transform the points to the CRS of the network
pt1_transformed <- st_transform(pt1, st_crs(net))
pt2_transformed <- st_transform(pt2, st_crs(net))

# Find the nearest points on the network to the transformed points of interest
n1 <- st_nearest_feature(pt1_transformed, net)
n2 <- st_nearest_feature(pt2_transformed, net)
```

From here, I create a "tbl_graph":

```
path <- net %>%
    activate(edges) %>%
    mutate(weight = edge_length()) %>%
    as_tbl_graph()

> path
# A tbl_graph: 430824 nodes and 570706 edges
#
# A directed multigraph with 442 components
#
# Edge Data: 570,706 x 25 (active)
   from    to OBJECTID NGD_UID NAME      TYPE  DIR   AFL_VAL ATL_VAL AFR_VAL ATR_VAL CSDUID_L CSDNAME_L   CSDTYPE~ CSDUID~ CSDNAME_R  CSDTYP~ PRUID_L PRNAME~ PRUID_R PRNAME~ RANK  CLASS                  `_ogr_geometry_` weight
  <int> <int>    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>       <chr>    <chr>   <chr>      <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr>                  <LINESTRING [m]>    [m]
1     1     2        4 3434819 NA        NA    NA    NA      NA      NA      NA      3526003  Fort Erie   T        3526003 Fort Erie  T       35      Ontario 35      Ontario 5     23    (7269806 859183, 7269795 859166.~   25.9
2     3     4        5 1358252 South     LINE  NA    NA      NA      NA      NA      3551027  Gordon/Bar~ MU       3551027 Gordon/Ba~ MU      35      Ontario 35      Ontario 5     23    (6921247 1133452, 6921258 113345~ 1245. 
3     5     6        8 1778927 NA        NA    NA    NA      NA      NA      NA      3512054  Wollaston   TP       3512054 Wollaston  TP      35      Ontario 35      Ontario 5     23    (7320857 1089403, 7320903 108942~  254. 
4     7     8       11 731932  Albion    RD    NA    NA      NA      2010    2010    3520005  Toronto     C        3520005 Toronto    C       35      Ontario 35      Ontario 3     21    (7202555 935281.3, 7202653 93533~  111. 
5     9    10       18 3123617 County 41 RD    NA    640     708     635     709     3511015  Greater Na~ T        3511015 Greater N~ T       35      Ontario 35      Ontario 3     21    (7403627 1039328, 7403431 103963~  367. 
6    11    12       20 4814160 NA        NA    NA    NA      NA      NA      NA      3553005  Greater Su~ CV       3553005 Greater S~ CV      35      Ontario 35      Ontario 5     21    (7042806 1222708, 7042838 122273~  191. 
# ... with 570,700 more rows
#
# Node Data: 430,824 x 1
    `_ogr_geometry_`
         <POINT [m]>
1   (7269806 859183)
2 (7269790 859162.7)
3  (6921247 1133452)
# ... with 430,821 more rows
```

From here, I am not sure how to use the tbl_graph to find the distance between the two points n1 and n2:

```
> n1
[1] 110393
> n2
[1] 319271
```

I think n1 and n2 correspond to the "to" and "from" columns in the "path" tbl_graph - but I am not sure how to use the tbl_graph to find out the distance between n1 and n2.

Can someone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `as_sfnetwork` creates a directed graph. This means all roads are one direction, defined (probably) by the order the vertices in the lines appear in the data.

To create an undirected graph, pass `directed=FALSE`.

I've cut down your road network to illustrate, so these numbers won't match the whole data set. I'm also working with the simplest `igraph` object before you mutate the weights etc.

```
net <- as_sfnetwork(a)
```

This is directed - all roads are one way - so no path between these two points:

```
net1  <- st_nearest_feature(pt1_transformed, net)
net2  <- st_nearest_feature(pt2_transformed, net)

sps = shortest_paths(net, net1, net2)
## Warning message:
## In shortest_paths(net, net1, net2) :
##   At core/paths/unweighted.c:368 : Couldn't reach some vertices.
```

Make it *un*directed:

```
net <- as_sfnetwork(a, directed=FALSE)
```

And now there's a way:

```
sps = shortest_paths(net, net1, net2)
sps
## $vpath
## $vpath[[1]]
## + > 
## 43/1040 vertices, from 8ad2ead:
##  [1]  547  501   74  402   99  107  108   82  350  164   33  177  229  113  114
## [etc]
```

If you have information about roads being one-way then you can probably add this to the graph structure at some point.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer!  I am interested in learning how to find the distance of this shortest path - should I post a new question about this? Thank you so much!

Comment: I asked it over here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/462029/calculating-the-distance-of-a-path-on-a-road-network