# Calculating the Distance of a Path on a Road Network

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

**Based on a shapefile, I am trying to find out the driving distance between two coordinates (e.g. CN Tower and Toronto Pearson Airport).**

First I loaded the shapefile:

```
library(sf)
library(rgdal)
library(sfnetworks)
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)
library(tidygraph)

# Set the URL for the shapefile
url <- "https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/RNF-FRR/files-fichiers/lrnf000r22a_e.zip"

# Create a temporary folder to download and extract the shapefile
temp_dir <- tempdir()
temp_file <- file.path(temp_dir, "lrnf000r22a_e.zip")

# Download the shapefile to the temporary folder
download.file(url, temp_file)

# Extract the shapefile from the downloaded zip file
unzip(temp_file, exdir = temp_dir)

# Read the shapefile using the rgdal package
# source: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/456748/strategies-for-working-with-large-shapefiles/456798#456798
a = st_read(file.path(temp_dir, "lrnf000r22a_e.shp"), query="select * from lrnf000r22a_e where PRUID_R ='35'")
```

The shapefile looks something like this:

```
Simple feature collection with 570706 features and 21 fields
Geometry type: LINESTRING
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 5963148 ymin: 665490.8 xmax: 7581671 ymax: 2212179
Projected CRS: NAD83 / Statistics Canada Lambert
First 10 features:
   OBJECTID NGD_UID       NAME TYPE  DIR AFL_VAL ATL_VAL AFR_VAL ATR_VAL CSDUID_L                           CSDNAME_L CSDTYPE_L CSDUID_R                           CSDNAME_R CSDTYPE_R PRUID_L PRNAME_L PRUID_R PRNAME_R RANK
1         4 3434819       <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  3526003                           Fort Erie         T  3526003                           Fort Erie         T      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
2         5 1358252      South LINE <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  3551027                Gordon/Barrie Island        MU  3551027                Gordon/Barrie Island        MU      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
3         8 1778927       <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  3512054                           Wollaston        TP  3512054                           Wollaston        TP      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
4        11  731932     Albion   RD <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    2010    2010  3520005                             Toronto         C  3520005                             Toronto         C      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    3
5        18 3123617  County 41   RD <NA>     640     708     635     709  3511015                     Greater Napanee         T  3511015                     Greater Napanee         T      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    3
6        20 4814160       <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  3553005     Greater Sudbury / Grand Sudbury        CV  3553005     Greater Sudbury / Grand Sudbury        CV      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
7        21 1817031       <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  3537028                         Amherstburg         T  3537028                         Amherstburg         T      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
8        24 4825761       <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  3554094 Timiskaming, Unorganized, West Part        NO  3554094 Timiskaming, Unorganized, West Part        NO      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
9        25  544891     Dunelm   DR <NA>       1       9       2      10  3526053                      St. Catharines        CY  3526053                      St. Catharines        CY      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
10       28 1835384 Seven Oaks   DR <NA>     730     974     731     975  3515005             Otonabee-South Monaghan        TP  3515005             Otonabee-South Monaghan        TP      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
   CLASS                 _ogr_geometry_
1     23 LINESTRING (7269806 859183,...
2     23 LINESTRING (6921247 1133452...
3     23 LINESTRING (7320857 1089403..
```

I then converted the shapefile into a graph network, defined the coordinates and changed the coordinate systems of both points:

```
# Convert the shapefile to an sfnetwork object
net <- as_sfnetwork(a, directed = FALSE)

# Define the two points of interest in WGS84 (EPSG:4326)
pt1 <- st_point(c(-79.61203, 43.68312))
pt2 <- st_point(c(-79.61203, 43.64256))

# Set the CRS of the points to WGS84 (EPSG:4326)
pt1 <- st_sfc(pt1, crs = 4326)
pt2 <- st_sfc(pt2, crs = 4326)

# Transform the points to the CRS of the network
pt1_transformed <- st_transform(pt1, st_crs(net))
pt2_transformed <- st_transform(pt2, st_crs(net))

# Find the nearest points on the network to the transformed points of interest
n1 <- st_nearest_feature(pt1_transformed, net)
n2 <- st_nearest_feature(pt2_transformed, net)
```

Finally, I then identified the shortest path between these two points:

```
sps = shortest_paths(net, net1, net2)
sps
## $vpath
## $vpath[[1]]
## + > 
## 43/1040 vertices, from 8ad2ead:
##  [1]  547  501   74  402   99  107  108   82  350  164   33  177  229  113  114
## [etc]
```

**My Question:** Now, I am trying to calculate the distance of this path.

I know in general how to calculate the distance of a network path in R:

```
# example for path distance calculation 
set.seed(123)
from <- sample(paste0("node_", 1:10), 20, replace = TRUE)
to <- sample(paste0("node_", 1:10), 20, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(from, to)
df <- unique(df)
df$weight <- runif(nrow(df))

g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
#plot(g, edge.width = df$weight * 5)

# distance of the path : node_3 -> node_9 -> node_5
d1 <- distances(g,"node_3","node_9")
d2 <- distances(g,"node_9","node_5")
total_distance <- as.numeric(d1) + as.numeric(d2)
#0.3845944
```

**But I am not sure how to perform to calculate for the shortest path for sps$vpath path.**

Can someone please show me how to do this?