# Rasterising multiple shapefiles into a single raster

Tags: python, raster, gdal, rasterio, geocube

I'm not even sure you can do this, but I want to convert multiple shapefiles into a single single-band raster.

I'm pretty sure its going to be easier to first create a multi-band raster and then use each combination of band values and a lookup table of some sort to assign a pixel a single value, producing a single-band raster. But I'm stuck on creating the initial multi-band raster.

Lets say I have 4 shapefiles (shp1, shp2, shp3, shp4).
The attribute table in each shapefile has a `shp_V` column that has an integer ranging from 5-8.
I want the raster to have 4 bands, one for each shapefile that equals the `shp_V` value of one of the shapefiles.

All examples I can find with `rasterio` or `gdal` only rasterises one shapefile, which I know how to do.

Currently I have this, but it obviously only converts one shapefile to one single-band raster:

```
attribute = 'shp_V'
shp1 = "Shapefiles/shp1.shp"
shp2 = "Shapefiles/shp2.shp"
shp3 = "Shapefiles/shp3.shp"
shp4 = "Shapefiles/shp4.shp"
out_tif = "Rasters/raster1234.tif"

cmd = 'gdal_rasterize -a {} -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE 
       -co BIGTIFF=YES -tr 0.3 0.3 {} {}'.format(attribute, shp1, out_tif)
print(cmd)
os.system(cmd)
```

The shapefiles and resulting rasters can get quite large, so any solutions which are a bit easier on processing power would also be a benefit.

Comment: You mention "I want to convert multiple shapefiles into a single single-band raster" and then later state "I want the raster to have 4 bands, one for each shapefile that equals the shp_V value of one of the shapefiles." Could you please clarify if you want a single band or multiband raster?

Comment: Oops yeah. Technically both, I've updated the question so hopefully it makes a bit more sense

Comment: GDAL_Rasterize -b <band index> https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html Not used when creating a new raster. You could consider rasterizing to single band rasters then use GDAL_Merge https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_merge.html to 'stack' the bands into a single raster or use driver.Create https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html (near the bottom) to make a multiband raster and then rasterize to each band in turn.

Comment: I would rasterize each shp then stack. This post may be helpful for the stacking: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/223910/8104

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend a combination of [geopandas](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas) and [geocube](https://github.com/corteva/geocube).

Here is some untested set of code that should get you pretty close to what you want to do.

Step 1: Combine the shapefiles

```
import pandas
import geopandas

gpd1 = geopandas.read_file("Shapefiles/shp1.shp")
gpd2 = geopandas.read_file("Shapefiles/shp2.shp")
gpd3 = geopandas.read_file("Shapefiles/shp3.shp")
gpd4 = geopandas.read_file("Shapefiles/shp4.shp")

merged_gpd = pandas.concat([gpd1, gpd2, gpd3, gpd4]).set_geometry("geometry")
```

Step 3: Rasterize the data

```py
from geocube.api.core import make_geocube

grid = make_geocube(
    vector_data=merged_gpd,
    measurements=["shp_V"],
    resolution=(-0.3, 0.3),
)
```

Step 4: Export to raster

```py
grid.shp_V.rio.to_raster("Rasters/raster1234.tif", compress="DEFLATE", bigtiff="YES")
```

Comment: This looks like a really clean solution, but the `pd.concat` causes a `MemoryError` due to the file sizes

Comment: If you have many columns in the shapfile and only need one, you could try this to reduce memory: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129414/only-read-specific-attribute-columns-of-a-shapefile-with-geopandas-fiona#129422

Comment: This got me very close! Thanks for the help :)